# Can configure generate .h files?

Tags: linux, autotools, configure

On Linux, when I execute `./configure` it generates header files and also .c files (besides Makefiles), right? How can I get configure to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by configure that? you can change the behavior of ./configure by using command line (run with --help) or you can recreate it using GNU AUTOTOOLs (Autoconfig/Automake)

Comment: What do you meant by ./configure? There are million configure scripts out there

Comment: You're using autoconf to generate a `configure` script and you want that `configure` script to generate a header file?

Comment: Yeah, this is my doubt. How can "configure" an ./configure to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to create a configure.ac (but depend on the autoconf version), but read [here](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming%3atut%3aautotools:2), to give you an idea what should you create and what is auto generated. It has good covered on the autotools topic.

Answer (score 2):

It's typically used to generate config header, that contains various defines (often libraries & function present or not). But this happens only if autotools were instructed to create configure doing that.

You define what goes to (and to which header exactly) in configure.ac (input file to autotools). See AC_CONFIG_HEADERS, AC_CHECK_HEADER, AC_CHECK_LIB and similar macros. See [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html) for details. Also read through complete tutorial jasonw linked. And see how things are done in some existing projects.